# How to avoid cascading while using default error handler in addition to custom error handler

Tags: vba, excel, error-handling

I use MZ Tools for Excel VBA at work, and I use their automatic error handler feature for most of my procedures because it allows me to easily put my contact information in the error message and automatically turn display alerts and screen updating back on.  But if an error handler is used in VBA, it becomes difficult to locate the exact line of code that triggered the error, especially in a longish procedure.  The default the only way I could figure out to use a custom error handler and get the line of code that triggered the error was to add these two lines to the end of the error handler (so that the problem line would be re-run with the default error handler after the custom error handler had done its work):

```
On Error GoTo 0
Resume
```

This works well if there is only one error handler; the user needs to click through one additional dialog box, but I can debug normally while maintaining the functionality built into my custom error handlers.  But if both the calling routine and subroutine have distinct error handlers, the user starts to get a lengthy cascade of similar-looking dialog boxes.  Precisely, I get 1 + n! dialogue boxes, where n is the number of levels of subroutines with error handlers.

The simplest way to illustrate the issue is when I run the first routine, I get 4 error messages instead of just 2:

```
Sub TstErrHndlr()

   On Error GoTo TstErrHndlr_Error1

    Call TstErrHndlrA

   On Error GoTo 0
   Exit Sub

TstErrHndlr_Error1:
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Call MsgBox("Error " & Err.Number & " (" & Err.Description _
            & ") in procedure TstErrHndlr " _
            & "of Module Create_Package." _
            & "  Contact [My Name] for assistance " _
            & "(myemal@company.com, (123)456-7890)")
    On Error GoTo 0
    Resume
End Sub

Sub TstErrHndlrA()

   On Error GoTo TstErrHndlrA_Error1

    Dim X As Double
    X = 1 / 0

   On Error GoTo 0
   Exit Sub

TstErrHndlrA_Error1:
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Call MsgBox("Error " & Err.Number & " (" & Err.Description _
            & ") in procedure TstErrHndlrA " _
            & "of Module Create_Package." _
            & "  Contact [My Name] for assistance " _
            & "(myemal@company.com, (123)456-7890")
   On Error GoTo 0
   Resume
End Sub
```

After going through the code in debug mode, it seems like **whenever a procedure is called by another procedure, whichever error handler was enabled in the calling function becomes the error handler that is enabled by the line `On Error GoTo 0` no matter how many times it is repeated.  I would like to know why VBA behaves this way, how to make it not behave this way, and/or if there is a better way to accomplish my goal of getting the line of code that triggered an error while using an error handler.**  I know that I could revert to the default error handler before a function is called with a new error handler (eg, `On Error GoTo 0: Call TstErrHndlrA`, but this makes for ugly confusing code, and will not handle errors that occur in the function call.

Comment: `OEG0` disables the error handler for the called routine. Therefore on a second error, control passes back to the calling routine and its error handler. I suggest you use conditional compilation for your On Error statements, or add line numbers and use `Erl`.

Comment: @Rory I'm not sure I understand the conditional compilation suggestion -- Do you mean that I would use conditional compilation to inactivate my error handlers for when I am the user, and activate them for any other user?  Or is there another way conditional compilation could solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest a restructure of your error handlers as follows

- Add a Debug mode for your own use, which breaks in the error handler and offers possibility of a resume to see the line causing the error
- Only raise the error popup at the level causing the actual error
- Reset Application properties at the top level only
- Lower level routine calls pass up unhandled errors

.

```
Option Explicit

' Debug Mode Flag (or you could use Conditional Compilation)
' Set to TRUE for developer mode debugging
Const DebugMode As Boolean = False ' True

Sub TstErrHndlr()
   On Error GoTo TstErrHndlr_Error1

   TstErrHndlrA

Exit Sub
TstErrHndlr_Error1:
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    ' display message if error is raised in this module
    If Err.Source = Application.VBE.ActiveVBProject.Name Then
        MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & " (" & Err.Description & ")" & vbLf & _
          "in procedure TstErrHndlr" & vbLf & _
          "Contact [My Name] for assistance " & _
          "(myemal@company.com, (123)456-7890)"
    End If
    ' Break in Debug mode
    If DebugMode Then
        Debug.Assert False
        Resume
    End If

End Sub

Sub TstErrHndlrA()
    On Error GoTo TstErrHndlrA_Error1

    Dim X As Double
    X = 1 / 0

Exit Sub
TstErrHndlrA_Error1:
' These should be handled at top level for unhandled errors only
'    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
'    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
'    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    ' display message if error is raised in this module
    If Err.Source = Application.VBE.ActiveVBProject.Name Then
        MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & " (" & Err.Description & ")" & vbLf & _
          "in procedure TstErrHndlrA" & vbLf & _
          "Contact [My Name] for assistance " & _
          "(myemal@company.com, (123)456-7890)"
    End If
    ' Break in Debug mode
    If DebugMode Then
        Debug.Assert False
        Resume
    End If
    ' Pass unhandled errors up the tree
    Err.Raise Err.Number, "TstErrHndlrA", Err.Description
End Sub
```

With Debug Mode OFF the user gets *one* popup identifying the error and routine it occurs in

With Debug Mode ON you also get a break in the routine causing the error, and the possibility of a Resume to the line causing the error. (Or use Ctrl-F9 to step over the Resume)

Comment: Great solutions overall, but can you explain why it matters that I pass up the unhandled error?  I guess there are times when I may want to do this if I had complicated error handling to reduce the risk of forgetting to update multiple error handlers if I changed something later on, but I don't see the harm in redundancy if I have ScreenUpdating and DisplayAlerts set true in my default MZ Tools error handler anyway.

Comment: General reasoning for errors: If a routine can recover from an error, handle it and move on.  If it can't recover pass it up.  The calling routine _may_ be able to handle and move on without stopping execution.  Same reason for not resetting Application properties: if the calling routine can handle the error you don't want those things reset

Answer (score 1):

From MSDN's [On Error](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa266173(v=vs.60).aspx) page:

> An "enabled" error handler is one that is turned on by an On Error statement; 
>   an "active" error handler is an enabled handler that is in the process
>   of handling an error. If an error occurs while an error handler is
>   active (between the occurrence of the error and a Resume, Exit Sub,
>   Exit Function, or Exit Property statement), the current procedure's
>   error handler can't handle the error. Control returns to the calling
>   procedure. If the calling procedure has an enabled error handler, it
>   is activated to handle the error. If the calling procedure's error
>   handler is also active, control passes back through previous calling
>   procedures until an enabled, but inactive, error handler is found. If
>   no inactive, enabled error handler is found, the error is fatal at the
>   point at which it actually occurred. Each time the error handler
>   passes control back to a calling procedure, that procedure becomes the
>   current procedure. Once an error is handled by an error handler in any
>   procedure, execution resumes in the current procedure at the point
>   designated by the Resume statement.

So to answer "Why does VBA behave this way": Because that's the way they made it.

To make it not behave this way, you will have to (as you mentioned) disable the current error handler with before calling the sub/function.

Using [ERL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/97sx19w1(v=vs.90).aspx#) as @Rory mentioned will get you the exact line where your code fails, and you might possibly be able to utilize `On Error Goto -1` in a broadly generic error trapping routine. It really comes down to being careful about calling other subs/functions, or having functions which can return an error code as their value (ie, bubbling the error up manually). For example, here's a function that returns the error as the value of the function rather than attempting to raise any kind of exception during the function call. You may also notice that some of the functions it calls might return errors as well.

```
Public Function SetTask(ByVal strHost As String, strUser As String, strDomain as String, strPass As String) As String
Dim service As Object
Dim rootFolder As Object
Dim taskDefinition As Object
Dim strCMD As String
Dim strResult As String

On Error GoTo TaskNotSet
SetTask = "Task Not Set"

'Open the firewall
strResult = OpenFirewall (strHost)
If strResult <> "Ok" Then
    SetTask = "Error Opening Firewall (" & err.Number & ") " & err.Description
    Exit Function
End If

Set service = CreateObject("Schedule.Service")
service.Connect strHost, strUser, strDomain, strPass

Set rootFolder = service.GetFolder("\")
Set taskDefinition = service.newtask(0)
taskDefinition.XmlText = TaskXML
Call rootFolder.RegisterTaskDefinition("Weekly VMC Inventory", taskDefinition, 6, , , 3)

'Close the firewall
strResult = CloseFirewall (strHost)
If strResult <> "Ok" Then
    SetTask = "Error Closing Firewall (" & err.Number & ") " & err.Description
    Exit Function
End If

SetTask = "Task Set"
Set taskDefinition = Nothing
Set rootFolder = Nothing
Set service = Nothing
Exit Function

TaskNotSet:
CloseFirewall (strHost)
SetTask = "Error Setting Task (" & err.Number & ") " & err.Description
Set taskDefinition = Nothing
Set rootFolder = Nothing
Set service = Nothing
End Function
```